# MYSQL SELECT valor posible de dos tablas

Tags: mysql, join, select

Tengo 2 tablas, una llamada 'familias' con campos 'id', 'email', y otra llamada 'progenitor' con campos 'id', 'id_familia', 'email' (simplificando el resto de los campos).

Necesito hacer un SELECT en el que se devuelva el email (en caso de haberlo) de la tabla "familias" y cada email de la tabla "progenitor" de esa familia, en caso de ser diferente al de la familia.

Tengo algo como:

```
SELECT progenitor.email AS correo_progenitor,
       familias.email AS correo_familia,
       FROM familias
       LEFT INNER JOIN progenitor
       ON progenitor.id_familia = familias.id
       WHERE progenitor.email IS NOT NULL
       AND familias.email <> ''
       AND progenitor.email <> familias.email
```

Lo que necesitaría es una lista de los correos no repetidos tanto de la tabla familias como progenitor. Con el código de arriba solo se muestran los de la tabla progenitor. No sé si sería cuestión de meter otro SELECT dentro pero quizás hay una fórmula más eficaz de este tipo.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El filtro por mails distintintos los tienes que hacer a nivel del `JOIN` si lo haces a nivel del `WHERE` no mostrarás las filas cuyo correo sea el mismo

```
SELECT  familias.id,
    progenitor.email    AS mail,
    familias.email      AS correo_familia
    FROM familias
    LEFT JOIN progenitor
        ON progenitor.id_familia = familias.id
        and IFNULL(progenitor.email, '') <> IFNULL(familias.email, '')
    WHERE   IFNULL(familias.email,'') <> ''
```

Por otro lado, ten en cuenta que al hacer esto: `IFNULL(familias.email,'') <> ''`, puedes no recuperar los casos en que no tengas mail en `familias` pero sí en `progenitor`. El uso del `IFNULL` es simplemente por que no tengo claro el comportamiento de las comparaciones con `NULL` en MySql.

Comment: Gracias Patricio.
Indudablemente está más cerca de la solución, pero no acaba de cuadrar. 
En el caso en el que la familia tenga un apellido, y cada progenitor otro, devuelve resultados que hay que parsear finalmente, pero podría servir.
En el caso en el que la familia tenga correo y NO ninguno de los progenitores, devuelve dos valores (con el correo de la familia), uno para cada progenitor. Está claro que podría hacer una simple comparación dentro del bucle while de lectura (comparando con un campo temp) pero me gustaría que el query fuera aún más limpio.